# Metasploit Search Multiple Keywords

Tags: databases, metasploit, postgresql

I am having an issue with Metasploit's search commands. When trying to search multiple keywords, the output displays only the first keyword. For example, if I use the command `search platform:windows type:exploit`, I will only receive the output of for Windows platforms, and include payloads, exploits, and post.

The only time this seems to work is when I disconnect the database, which isn't an acceptable answer as that removes all of the database command abilities. I have also tried rebuilding the database but this problem persists.

Does anyone have a solution to this? I am running Metasploit Version 4.13.1-dev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR - upgrade, it works like you expect now.

In versions before 4.13.8, `search` used a *union* instead of an *intersection* of results. Thus your example ("search platform:windows type:exploit") would show you all modules that target Windows (including payloads, auxiliary, and post modules) *and* all modules that are exploits (regardless of the platform they target).

After that release (early December 2016), `search` now does what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Inside an older version of msfconsole, you could call grep immediately before calling the search command.
For example, to search for the 2 terms '*shellshock*' and '*mod_cgi*':

```
msf > grep mod_cgi search shellshock
auxiliary/scanner/http/apache_mod_cgi_bash_env     2014-09-24       normal     Apache mod_cgi Bash Environment Variable Injection (Shellshock) Scanner
exploit/multi/http/apache_mod_cgi_bash_env_exec    2014-09-24       excellent  Apache mod_cgi Bash Environment Variable Code Injection (Shellshock)
```

To search for the 3 terms '*shellshock*', '*mod_cgi*', and '*exploit*':

```
msf > grep 'exploit/.+.mod_cgi' search name shellshock
exploit/multi/http/apache_mod_cgi_bash_env_exec                   2014-09-24       excellent  Apache mod_cgi Bash Environment Variable Code Injection (Shellshock)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
msfconsole -qx "search platform:windows" | grep exploit
```

Comment: Does this work inside the msfconsole?

Comment: No, that's the whole point. It works